# What's the simplest way to execute a method with administrator privileges?

Tags: c#, .net, process, administration

I am currently just calling my own program in a new process with:

```
MyProcessStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
MyProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "MyFlag";
```

And when the process starts I check for the flag. If it's there – I just execute the method and `Close();`

But I would rather do something more minimalistic if it could be done simply. Is that possible?

EDIT: Using Vista and Windows7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not elevate a running process. It's *simply* not possible. You are doing it the correct way, by spawning another process with elevated priviledges. There is no other way.

> Thanks. but I was thinking maybe there is a way to start a method as a new process.

You could create a separate application executable that has your method in it, then you would not need to restart your application. You would only need to start that other process.

Comment: Thanks. But I was thinking maybe there is a way to start a method as a new process.

Comment: An app with privilige X spawnning another app with privilige X+1 will not be accomplished in windows 7 and above. it will still be running in privilige X (not X+1). unless things has changed since I last attempted that 6 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't minimalistic, but you can use this property I crafted from sources on the net.  Some of these calls are pInvoke's.  So google 'pinvoke method' to find them.

```
public static bool IsRunAsAdministrator
{
    get
    {
        WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        if (windowsIdentity.IsSystem) return true;

        WindowsPrincipal windowsPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(windowsIdentity);
        if (windowsPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
            return true;

        //Vista or higher check
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
        {
            IntPtr hToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, out hToken))
                    Win32.ThrowLastError();

                TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE elevationType;
                IntPtr pElevationType = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE));
                uint dwSize;

                if (!GetTokenInformation(
                    hToken,
                    TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenElevationType,
                    pElevationType,
                    sizeof(TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE),
                    out dwSize
                    ))
                    Win32.ThrowLastError();

                elevationType = (TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE)Marshal.ReadInt32(pElevationType);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pElevationType);

                return elevationType == TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE.TokenElevationTypeFull;
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseHandle(hToken);
            }
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I think I'll stick to simple managed code.

Comment: If you find something simple, please share.  I'd love for something that worked in every case on every operating system.

Comment: +1. for way to check for privileges. @inspiro make sure to keep check for flag in place - if you just try to perform operation when your code have enough privileges it may unexpectedly perform operation when run on machine with UAC turned off.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't quite understand what you meant.

Comment: @ispiro, I.e. you special operation is "delete important file" and your program always performs it as soon as it finds it has enough permissions (rather than checking if "/deleteImportantFile" option is specified) than simple fact of launching the program may (in case of UAC turned off for the admin account) trigger deletion of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You may use use Windows API `LogonUser` and then impersonate another user to run a piece of code as that user. There is a limitation though. When UAC is enabled `LogonUser` will give you restricted user token which means impersonated user (even administrator) will never get more rights than you already have. This restriction does not apply to non-interactive sessions (Windows services).

Here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx) on how to impersonate in a code. Also, you may find [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098121/how-can-i-get-elevated-permissions-uac-via-impersonation-under-a-non-interacti) interesting.